# How to enforce initial value (zero) is exported to Prometheus with OpenTelemetry

Tags: java, prometheus, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

Considering the following code that defines a simple counter:

```java
OpenTelemetry otel = ...

var meter = otel.getMeter("com.my.app");

LongCounter MyCounter = meter
  .counterBuilder("my_app_my_counter")
  .build();
```

As long as we don't increment the value of the counter (with `.add(1, ...)` for instance), the counter value is not visible to Prometheus scraping.

**How to have the initial value (zero) visible to Prometheus from the beginning?**

For completeness, here's the code we use to expose metrics to Prometheus thanks to OpenTelemetry Prometheus module:

```java
import io.opentelemetry.exporter.prometheus.PrometheusHttpServer

PrometheusHttpServer prometheusServer = ...

SdkMeterProvider meterProvider = SdkMeterProvider
  .builder()
  .setResource(...)
  .registerMetricReader(prometheusServer)
  .build();

OpenTelemetrySdk openTelemetrySdk = OpenTelemetrySdk
  .builder()
  .setMeterProvider(meterProvider)
  .buildAndRegisterGlobal();
```

Comment: What about `.add(0, ..)`?

Comment: @markalex it works, thanks! If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: For anyone coming here, see also https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/discussions/5939

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely counter is initialized only once first access is happening.

So, the easiest way to initialize it is to invoke `.add` method after metric creation with value equal to 0.